# GMaps v3 Markers AddListener Getting always the last variable index in the for loop

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

GMaps v3 Markers AddListener Problem

I'm trying to add mouseover/mouseout event listener to my markers, but I get allways the last value of the for loop In all the events, It seems to get the last value of the for instead the current. Here is my code

```
for( mark in data ) {
    markers[mark] = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[mark].lat,data[mark].lng), map: map,
            });
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[mark], "mouseover", function() {
                alert(mark);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[mark], "mouseout", function() {
                alert(mark);
            });
        }
```

The result is an alert on mouse over/out with the same value for all 10 markers and I was expecting the marker id on each alert.

thanks
Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you are having is the value of mark is global and is left set to the last value in the loop.  The issue can be fixed with a function closure.  I think this will work (not tested):

```
 function createMarker(latlng, id)
 {
    var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng, map: map,
          });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
            alert(id);
          });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
            alert(id);
          });
    return marker;
 }
 for( mark in data ) {
   markers[mark] = createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(data[mark].lat,data[mark].lng),
                                mark);
 }
```